# Order Items Creation Error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a shopping cart for a peer to peer marketplace and am puzzled by the current error I'm experiencing and I would love if someone could explain why this error is occurring.

This is what I have in my Application Controller:

```
def current_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    end
    if session[:cart_id].nil?
      @current_cart = Cart.create!
      session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
    end
    @current_cart
  end 

  def current_order 
     @item = Item.find(params[:id]) #here is where the problem lies, but I'm not sure why
     Order.find_or_create_by(seller_id: @item.user_id )
  end
```

Here is my OrderItems Controller:

```
def create
    @cart = current_cart
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

 def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity_requested, :item_id, :size_requested, :seller_id)
  end
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Item without an ID):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:29:in `current_order'
  app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:4:in`create'

I'm puzzled bc the Order saves w/ the correct seller id but the OrderItem isn't created.  Can anyone point out where my mistake is or why I'm getting this error?  The app seems to be able to find the item id from the db to create the order, just not the order item.  So confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your order_items_params method.

Comment: Posted!  Please let me know if any other info can help.  Thanks!

Comment: What are your params? If you're in the order_items_controller, most likely your :id is going to belong to an order_item not item. So if you pass that ID to look for Items, you'll retrieve the wrong record(or the correct one by mistake)

Comment: It's a problem because there aren't any params, or at least no ID param, hence there's nothing to find.

Comment: Try permitting :id in your strong params.

Comment: There won't be an ID for an order that hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Try changing this `@item = Item.find(params[:id])` to `@item = Item.find(params[:item_id])`

Comment: I'd need to see the URL and your routes.rb file but at first glance it sounds like you aren't actually getting an ID parameter for your controller. If you look at the console output from your rails app you can see the exact parameters that are supplied to your controller.